# How to add search for select in materialize css framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I am new in materialize CSS framework and I am looking for searchable select.

I have added select component but now I want it to be searchable so that user can search value from dropdown options and select the value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete?

Comment: not exactly. I want select box but with search option. materializecss autocomplete behaves differently.

Comment: Did you add a textbox which displays a div containing the dropdown upon clicking? Do you have something like ? http://i.imgur.com/ct4JGyK.png

Comment: I am working on select from [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) library so I am concerning about there select box

Comment: @bitto yeah, you need to have a text input too right so that the user can search for the options. You should replace the checkbox list with your list of options. When the user clicks on some option, the text should be reflected in the textbox (can be done using Jquery/JS). PS. add an '@' tag when you comment tagging the user with whom you want to communicate otherwise they wont get a notification.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution to this problem is to set `minLength:0` when using [Autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) - this essentially triggers the dropdown options on focus, and allows for searching or selecting.

**The HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
<label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
```

**The JS:**

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, {
   data: {
      "Apple": null,
      "Microsoft": null,
      "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
   minLength: 0, 
});
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/zYGrXjJ).

Answer (score 2):

I have been searching for this option for quite a while. After digging deeper into materialize Git Hub threads found this answer from [LeMinaw](https://github.com/LeMinaw)

he got everything nailed out. but he was using a custom materialize file and also it wasn't working on the mobile. So, I have modified the code to fix mobile issue. Please use import the following script file after you imported the Materialize.js file [MaterilizeSelect.js](https://github.com/lkusam/MySite/blob/master/JS/MaterilizeSelect.js).

and format your select as following

```
 <div class="input-field col s6">
            <select data-id="26" id="MySelct" serachname="myselectsearch" searchable="your placeholder for seach box">
              <option value="some1">Some One</option>
              <option value="SeamSeam">SeamSeam</option>
              <option value="toott">Toott</option>
              <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
            </select>
            <label for="roof_type">My Select</label>
</div>
```

- serachname --> A meaning fullname for search box
- searchable -->   placeholder your search box(label)

Hope this helps. Once again thanks to LeMinaw

Comment: The link is dead for MaterilizeSelect.js.

Comment: @ShaidaMuhammad Made the repo public. You should have access now.

Comment: the link is not working for MaterializeSelect.js

Comment: @LReddy the repo is still not public / doesn't work.

Comment: @JerryLupo. Made it public again. I think one of my collaborators made is private. Just made the whole thing public again. Can you try again.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3096) on github.

[LeMinaw](https://github.com/LeMinaw)'s solution:

> Improvements :
>
> No need to modify Materialize JS files Grabs keyboard focus nicely No
> need for annoying JQuery Renders correctly for any widget width Demo
>
> The code is avalaible in this gist :
> https://gist.github.com/LeMinaw/52675dae35531999e22f670fb66d389b
>
> To use it, just load this JS file and add `searchable="placeholder"` to
> your select element.

Comment: Amazing, worked on single select without any changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Materialize's search option just isn't great.  You could work with these to try to "fix" it, but you're better off just utilizing a better select javascript package, like Select2, which does all this easily. https://select2.org/getting-started/installation

I use materialize for lots of things, but always strengthen it with Select2 (and some other form UI libraries).